# Core Data: What difference between insertNewObject vs designated initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have found two solutions to the problem:

```
public class MyClass: NSManagedObject {
    init(_ entity:NSEntityDescription, dict: NSDictionary, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        super.init(entity: entity , insertInto: context)
    }
}

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyClass", in: self.context!)
_ = MyClass.init(entity!, dict: item as! NSDictionary, context: self.context!)
```

and

```
let myClass = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MyClass", into: context) as! MyClass
```

but I cannot understand the difference in the end. And how does it affect `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: I was not aware of the first version, but I have got a 3rd for you: `let createe = MyClass(context: context)`, which I prefer to avoid the need of knowing the entities name.

Comment: [official doc here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription/1425093-insertnewobject) does mention the relationship between insertNewObject and init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The have the same effect. The method on `NSEntityDescription` is a "factory" method, which you don't see too often in Objective-C (that method existed before Swift did). But the end result is the same as using the designated initializer. Although the factory method's code is not available, you can assume that it calls the designated initializer at some point.

Answer (score 1):

**init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?)** initializer available for iOS 3.0+

**init(context: NSManagedObjectContext)** initializer available for iOS 10.0+

I use both initializers to maintain compatibility with iOS < 10.0, there is no difference between them.